# How to determine Visual Studio Setup and Deployment project prerequisites?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment

I am trying to deploy an app in C# with a Setup And Deployment project in VS2010. The main project and the deployment project are in the same solution and I have added the primary output of the main project to the deployment project. In the property pages for the deployment project, there is a button for prerequisites. How do I find out what items my app will require for successful deployment?

Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio will manage all the requisite DLL's that need to be installed for your application to run... If still you need to add more dependencies then you could create an application that will handle this process for you.

And since Microsoft has an easy solution for almost everything, there are options to the installer to do just this. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eh4aaa5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) you'll find it as per MS documentation.

Comment: Thanks.. If I understand correctly, does this mean I can uncheck all the boxes in the Prerequisites dialog and my app should install fine?

Comment: Only if you are absolutely certain that such prerequisites will be met by the client. If they don't (I can't guarantee you this but) I THINK no description of the error (that will most likely arise during installation) will be given.

Comment: Sorry, my question actually was, how do I find out what my application's prerequisites are? In the solution explorer, I can see that I have some detected dependencies. As long as they are detected, does this guarantee that they will be included in the deployment? Say for example it says Microsoft .NET Framework as one of the dependencies, do I have to manually check the box in the Prerequisites dialog that says .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 or whatever framework I am using? Thanks..

Comment: That should be done automatically. If your app (or any of the prerequisite-apps detected) need a specific framework it should be automatically selected in the Prerequisites Dialog. And yes, if they are detected and are showing in the Solution Explorer under "Detected Dependencies" then they should install with the installer and be available to the running app.

Comment: So why is it I am allowed to deselect all the prerequisites? The project's detected dependencies list Microsoft .NET Framework as a dependency but it is allowing me to deselect .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 in the "Choose which prerequisites to install:" list.. "Create setup program to install prerequisite components" is checked.. :(

Comment: Visual Studio gives you the option to uncheck dependencies... that does not mean you should. If you deselect the "Create Setup Program to install prerequisites components" you will still have the installer but -AFAIK- it won't manually check for nor install dependencies. Perhaps this will help clarify http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tx0bw8y.aspx

Comment: i would like to ask the exact same question. how do I find out what my application's prerequisites are? would appreciate if anyone would give me answer.

Comment: @publicEnemy are you also using deploying with a setup?

Comment: Then what is it that you need that hasn't been answered already? The dependencies are automatically handled for you. And the prerequisites will basically be the .Net framework it runs on and any 3rd party DLL you actually use in your code and their dependencies (any unused reference will be ignored by the packager).

Answer (score 0):

Right click your `project` => `propereties` => `Application` => `Target Framework`